# Help with the Integral of $x \arcsin x\,dx$

Tags: integration

So I've started the integration using integration by parts, but I'm stuck on the second part of it.

$$ \int_0^\frac{1}{2} x \sin^{-1}x dx $$

- **Step 1**. Set up my variables
         $$ u = \arcsin x $$ 
         $$du = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}} dx $$ 
         $$ dv = x dx $$
         $$ v = \frac{x^{2}}{2} $$
- **Step 2.** $uv - \int v\,du$
        $$ \frac{x^2}{2} \arcsin x   - \frac{1}{2} \int x^{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}$$
- **Step 3.** Now I need to integrate $ \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} $

This is where I'm stuck. Do I do a trig sub? Let $x = \sin\theta$ which $1-\sin^2\theta$ would then equal $\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}$ turning the second part into $\int \sec \theta$?

**Edit. Attempting to continue the problem with the suggestions provided.**

- **Step 3 (continued)**. $$ \frac{-1}{2} \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx $$
  $$ \text{Let }x = \sin \theta $$
  $$ -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sin^2\theta \cos\theta}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}} $$
  $$ -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sin^2\theta \cos\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta}} $$
  $$ -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sin^2\theta \cos\theta}{\cos\theta} $$
  $$ -\frac{1}{2} \int \sin^2\theta  $$
  $$ -\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{1 - \cos2\theta}{2} $$
  $$ -\frac{1}{4} [\theta-\sin\theta \cos\theta] $$
- **Step 4**. Find what $\theta$ is equal to in terms of x.
  Since we let $x = \sin\theta$, that would mean we have $$x^2 + b^2 = 1^2$$
  So, does that mean I substitute $$ 1 - x$$ in for $\theta$?

Comment: integrating arcsin and derivating $x$ is way easier

Comment: First of all you need to realize that if you do the substitution as per your wish the second part will turn into an integral over $sin^{2}\theta$ which can be solved.

Comment: Edit: Sorry, bad wording prior to the edit. Jossie, I wasn't aware how to integrate arcsin which is why I chose to derive it. I'll look up on how to integrate it. Sudarsan, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Could you show me?

Comment: You are doing fine. I think you know what is $\int \sec t dt $.

Comment: @ConfusingCalc If $x=sin\theta$, then $dx = cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$. Now $\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\mathrm{d}x$ is equal to $\frac{sin^{2}\theta cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta}{cos\theta}$ leading to what I said.

Comment: @Sudarsan Ah, for some reason I changed the $x^2$ on top to a 1. Indeed, it would have to be $sin^2(\theta)$ if I let $x = sin\theta$. Wouldn't that make it $\frac{sin^2\theta}{cos\theta} $rather than $\frac{sin^2\theta cos\theta}{cos\theta}$?

Comment: @Jossie You "differentiate" functions.

Comment: Thanks Peter, English is not my first language.

Comment: @ConfusingCalc No. There's a $\mathrm{d}x$ term which is adding a term to the numerator equal to $cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$.

Comment: And integrating $sin^{2}\theta$ is simple because $sin^{2}\theta$ is equal to $\frac{1-cos2\theta}{2}$.

Comment: I've attempted to follow Sudarsan's suggestion, can I get some confirmation or more guidance?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue with step (3), then you can use integration by parts again with $u=x$

$$ \int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx = -x\sqrt {-{x}^{2}+1}+\int \!\sqrt {1-{x}^{2}}{dx}.$$

For the last integral, you can use the trig. subs $x=\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Why not to make the same substitution in the first integral?

Comment: It's the same and I believe applying at the very beginning is a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Thank you @Mhenni. I'm going to try and do it with the trig substitution in the first part and see how it goes.